# How can view two month comparison data from one column and show as present and previous as per date range

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT itemcode,itemname,(SUM(good)+SUM(bad)) as prdn,SUM(good) as good,SUM(bad) as bad,concat(round(((SUM(bad)/(SUM(good)+SUM(bad)))*100),0),'%') as PresentRejection,
concat(round(((SUM(bad)/(SUM(good)+SUM(bad)))*100),0),'%') as PreviousRejection
FROM tb_data 
WHERE date BETWEEN '2022-07-01' AND '2022-07-14' 
GROUP BY itemcode 
ORDER BY good DESC;
```

I want to show PresentRejection and PreviousRejection data beside one another. PreviousRejection date will be '2022-06-01'AND '2022-06-30', Now how can I do this?

Comment: Use conditional aggregation.

Comment: How can use conditional aggregation?